# Loop over the result of db query promises in nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Hi I have `nodejs` application in which I am using `PostgreSQL` for `DB`. I have below in my method to get employee data

```
const result = await DBService.query(EmpQuery.getEmployeeId());

const empPromises = [];

for (const empAccount of result.rows) {
   try {
     const empId = empAccount.empid;
     const QueryObj = new EmpQuery(empId);
     empPromises.push(DBService.query(QueryObj.getCurrentEmployee())); // from employeeTable
     empPromises.push(DBService.query(QueryObj.getEmployeeWithDept())); // from dept table.
   } catch (error) {
    logger.info(error);
 }
}
const promiseresult = await Promise.all(empPromises);
```

I have both query result in `promiseresult`. I want to update another table based on `promiseresult` only when both query result has data. How can loop over the `promiseresult` and check if both table result has data then update the table.

Comment: Just loop over `promiseresult` in step of two, and compare each even-indexed element with the following odd-indexed element?

Comment: Hi Bergi, thank you for your comment, I am new to nodejs and JS, can you please provide some sample code for above.